# Syntax Error/How to do minimum on Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, min

I've been trying to do a minimum code and for some reason theres a syntax error. If you know what mistake I'm making please tell me. Also, if I'm doing the code wrong it would be great if you suggested another approach to the problem.

[[image]]

Comment: You've forgotten a colon at the end of the if-statement

Comment: Please, post the code instead of picture of your code.

Comment: What on earth is the point of posting a *link* to a *picture* of your code? Why not post the actual code, here?

Answer (score 2):

Python has built-in function [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) that returns the minimum item in given iterable, why not use that?

```
print min([4, 7, 1, 8]) # 1
```